# std::map iterator output order will be constant if map keys/values don't change?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, std

is the output order of a map::iterator guaranteed if I don't change the keys/values in that map?

E.g., I initialize a map with some keys/values then do a sequence of loops and in each loop iterate over the map and perform read-only actions, will the output of each iteration be equal?

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
 for(it=map.begin(); it!=map.end(); it++)
  // read some value from map
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`std::map` is an ordered collection. Iterating from `begin()` to `end()` will always return map entries in order.

The order is determined by the comparison operator of the map which is `std::less<Key>` by default.

In a word: yes.

Answer (score 0):

the order is only modified on modify operations (insert, erase, clear), other operations will not impact the ordering

Answer (score 0):

`std::map` guarantees to be sorted. If contents don't change, map sorting shouldn't.

I can only think of a scenario in which this may not happen: map keys are pointers and comparison functor dereferences objects pointed by keys to perform comparison operations on them. Keys are not changed but values pointed by do (for any other reason). And even there I'm not sure if the standard forces implementation of `std::map` to evaluate comparison only at the time of inserting elements.

Comment: This would be an illegal comparison relation as the comparison would not yield a strict weak ordering on the keys if the comparison could yield different answers at different times.